# Writing binary number system in C code

Tags: c

As we use `0x` prefix for hexadecimal numbers, and `0` for octal ones, is there anything that can be done for binary numbers?

I tried the `b` suffix, but the [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) didn't allow it.

> Error: invalid suffix "b" on integer constant

Is it possible?

Comment: Binary literals don't exist in C. The closest you have are hexadecimal, as they follow the binary bitpattern closely.

Comment: Hex to binary is really easy to convert.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Standard C doesn't define binary constants. There's a GNU C extension though (among popular compilers, clang adapts it as well): the `0b` or `0B` prefixes:

```
int foo = 0b1010;
```

If you want to stick with standard C, then there's an option: you can combine a macro and a function to create an *almost* readable "binary constant" feature:

```
#define B(x) S_to_binary_(#x)

static inline unsigned long long S_to_binary_(const char *s)
{
        unsigned long long i = 0;
        while (*s) {
                i <<= 1;
                i += *s++ - '0';
        }
        return i;
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
int foo = B(1010);
```

If you turn on heavy compiler optimizations, the compiler will most likely eliminate the function call completely (constant folding) or will at least inline it, so this won't even be a performance issue.

**Proof:**

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>


#define B(x) S_to_binary_(#x)

static inline unsigned long long S_to_binary_(const char *s)
{
    unsigned long long i = 0;
    while (*s) {
        i <<= 1;
        i += *s++ - '0';
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int foo = B(001100101);

    printf("%d\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

has been compiled using `clang -o baz.S baz.c -Wall -O3 -S`, and it produced the following assembly:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $101, %esi               ## <= This line!
    xorb    %al, %al
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str1:                                ## @.str1
    .asciz   "%d\n"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

So `clang` completely eliminated the call to the function, and replaced its return value with `101`. Neat, huh?

Comment: The next question then is, why did you write `foo = [long mess of binary numbers]` rather than `foo = CONSTANT1 | CONSTANT2 | ...;`. What did the binary number achieve?

Comment: @Lundin Huh? The point is readability and having **binary literals**.

Comment: And my point is that there exists no situation where binary literals are more readable than something else, more suitable, such as #defined bit masks.

Comment: @Lundin Did I argue against that? OP asked "how is this possible", and I've shown him how. Time to leave me alone.

Comment: "The point is readability..." is an argument in favour of binary literals indeed.

Comment: @Lundin You didn't get the point. Some argued that octal and hexadecimal literals are enough - and while they are enough, if one wants a bit pattern, the reading `11001001101` is easier than `0xc02` - I don't know how it may concern you, but for me, the binary representation of a hexadecimal literal is not obvious at first glance. Maybe it is for you.

Comment: @Lundin No need to downvote.

Comment: @Lundin There are lots of situations where lots of people would find binary numbers more readable. In fact, when defining enums with lots of flags, many programmers will annotate every constant with its binary value in a comment. And in fact now that C++ provides user-defined literals, the first one many people implement is an extension for binary number literals.

Comment: @H2CO3 I haven't voted in either direction for this answer.

Comment: And I don't think there is no further point in arguing this subject, since whether binary numbers are more or less readable is apparently very subjective. I find hex easier to read, others don't.

Comment: @Lundin - Take it from someone who has worked with lots of embedded hardware: We often have to deal with binary values that don't begin with their low bit in bit 0 as far as the CPU's data bus is concerned.  Of course, macros that take a value & shift it for you come in quite useful in that case and handle the readability issues, sometimes it's nice to be able to simply specify a binary literal.  I've found as I've grown more accustomed to embedded programming that my "need" for binary literals has dropped to nearly zero, but in the beginning they would have seemed like they would be handy.

Comment: @H2CO3 - It is indeed 'neat' that clang can optimize that function (with a loop!) down to a single constant.  In my testing, GCC isn't able to do that, at least not in version 4.7.2.  With -O3, GCC 4.7.2 merely inlines it.  And if your printf() call is replaced with `printf("%lld   0x%llx\n", B(001100101), B(001100101));`, it inlines it twice... with two completely different generated forms of the assembly.

Comment: Inlining is great... if used judiciously, and for truly trivial functions.  This is a case where it isn't great.  If your compiler can't optimize S_to_binary_() into a constant, then far more time will spent loading an extra copy of the inlined function than would be spent in function call overhead.  If it's NOT inlined, the function would be loaded into the cache on the first call,...

Comment: ...and the second call would be nearly free, from an instruction fetch standpoint (but not as free as with clang, it appears!).  In addition, if this function is called a lot, then the cache will be consumed with tons of copies of it, taking the place of other useful code that has to be evicted to make room for a bunch of inlined copies of S_to_binary_().

Answer (score 17):

Prefix you literal with `0b` like in

```
int i = 0b11111111;
```

See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html).

Comment: It's an extension though, and may need a special flag for `gcc` to understand it. And of course not portable to other compilers that doesn't support that extension.

Answer (score 7):

Use [BOOST_BINARY](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#BOOST_BINARY) (Yes, you can use it in C).

```
#include <boost/utility/binary.hpp>
...
int bin = BOOST_BINARY(110101);
```

This macro is expanded to an octal literal during preprocessing.

Comment: I get an error when I use BOOST_BINARY with a variable: #include <stdio.h> #include <boost/utility/binary.hpp> int main() { int bin; printf("Enter your binary number: "); scanf("%i", &bin); printf("The decimal value is %d", BOOST_BINARY(bin)); return 0; }

The error says error: macro "BOOST_DETAIL_SPLIT_AND_SWAP_PARAMS" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given

Comment: It's not a good idea to mix in a huge library like boost in most programs. Especially if they are made to be small and fast to compile. Since C already supports it through extension, I would advise anyone to build around that and switch it up with version macros.