# Including arithmetic operations when defining a constant

Tags: c++, constants, c-preprocessor

So I often see something like this:

```
#define gf_PI  f32(3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510)
#define gf_PIhalf  f32(3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510 * 0.5)
```

This means that half PI value is calculated every time I use gf_PIhalf in my code, right?
Wouldn't it be better to literally write the value of half PI instead?

Wouldn't it be even better to do the following:

```
#define gf_PI f32(3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510)
const float gf_PIHalf = gf_PI * 0.5f;    // PIHalf is calculated once
```

Finally wouldn't it be best to do it like this (and why it doesn't seem to be a common practice):

```
const float gf_PI = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510;
const float gf_PIHalf = gf_PI * 0.5f;
```

Comment: do you really care if your program does one multiplication more ? is it really that critical ?

Comment: This is a great question.  I once asked a similar question about memory constraints and efficiency, and I think the standard answer I received was similar to "Honestly, at this rate, it doesn't matter.  It's such a small amount of data that the ratio of efficiency doesn't take much of a hit."  I think in this case, You'll find that the efficiency of the program doesn't necessarily suffer VS. the idea that you get a re-calculation that you can trust every time.

If you're confident in the arithmetic, I'd go for pure efficiency.

Comment: See, a good compiler optimizes away [even a complete mess like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114140/writing-binary-number-system-in-c-code/15114188#15114188) into one constant...

Comment: @Smash: Well, it's not likely to become a bottleneck but if the multiplication operation would in fact occur every time and it would be used in a critical loop called very often then I don't see a reason why not to make sure it doesn't occur by using one of the other solutions.

Comment: @plast1K: It's a constant. Recalculating it every time doesn't make me trust it anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This means that half PI value is calculated every time I use gf_PIhalf in my code, right?

Nope, not likely.

You can reasonably count on your compiler to do that multiplication at compile time, not runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Your conclusions are somewhat right, except that the `#define` version will almost definitely resolve in compile time and the bit about types const globals being uncommon practice. They are common practice in modern good code. `#define`s are all but dead for this use. The *best* practice is to define your file scope globals in an unnamed namespace:

```
namespace
{
    const float g_SomeGlobal = 123.456f;
}
```

This prevents anyone outside of your translation unit from being able to 'see' `g_SomeGlobal`.