# Is there an efficient way to construct b10101010101010101010101010101010?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I want to construct the unsigned integer (4 bytes) represented by the binary string 10101010101010101010101010101010 (that's 16 1s and 16 0s).

Is there an efficient way to construct this value using bit manipulation? I could do it in a for loop, but I feel that's inefficient.

Any language works for me. I personally know c and C++.

Comment: Uh, isn't it 0xAAAAAAAA? Just make a string of length 4 whose chars are `0xAA`...

Comment: Wow, wait ... how'd you figure that out so fast? :O

Comment: @DavidFaux `1010` in binary is decimal 10 (it's easy to remember, for this exact same reason). And decimal 10 is `A` in hexadecimal.

Comment: @DavidFaux: Because A in hex is 1010 in binary.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Because he lives so close to the hexadecimal numbers that they are all his close friends.

Comment: @DavidFaux: it is really obvious. 0xaa // 0x55 used to be used to perform RAM tests, etc. The first/last two bytes of the boot sector used to be aa55, too, IIRC.

Comment: @wildplasser hehe now you're just showing off +1 for that

Comment: By the way, if you want to [have binary literals in C, that's possible too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114140/writing-binary-number-system-in-c-code/15114188#15114188)

Comment: Is this question a joke?

Comment: Many languages support bit syntax. Why dont you tell us what you are using?

Comment: It's a constant, why do you want to "construct" it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read bits 4 by 4 and treat them as hex:

your number is just 0xAAAAAAAA.

Answer (score 1):

With a fixed number of bits, this is a bit obvious...

But for a variable number of bits, such pattern can be obtained by integer division as demonstrated here http://smallissimo.blogspot.fr/2011/07/revisiting-sieve-of-erathostenes.html

**EDIT** More detailed explanations below:

The idea is that :

```
2r01 * 2r11 -> 2r11
2r0101 * 2r11 -> 2r1111
2r010101 * 2r11 -> 2r111111
```

So inversely, we can apply an exact division:

```
2r111111 / 2r11 -> 2r010101
```

If we want `2r101010` rather than `2r010101`, just add 1 more bit (but the division is then inexact, I assume quotient is given by // like in Smalltalk) :

```
2r1111111 // 2r11 -> 2r101010
```

`2r1111111` can be constructed easily, it is a power of 2 minus 1, `2^7-1`, which can also be obtained by a bith shift `(1<<7)-1`.

In your case, your constant is `((1<<33)-1)//3`, or if you write it in C/C++ `((1ULL<<33)-1)/3`
(In Smalltalk we don't care of integer length, they are of arbitrary length, but in most language we must make sure the operands fits on a native integer length).

Note that division also work for bit patterns of longer length like `2r100100100`, divide by `2r111`, and for a bit pattern of length p, divide by `2^p-1` that is `(1<<p)-1`

Comment: That was not a question.

Comment: @RamonSnir The question is how to construct, so this might be an answer, though I agree, the answer is useless if the pattern is of fixed length

Comment: At least summarize the formula `(2^64-1)*2/3` (the article is long and mostly irrelevant). But the question was about fixed size. I will not that this "trick" doesn't work for all powers of two, only the even ones.

Comment: @RamonSnir yes it was a lazy answer, because too much for calculating a constant! But the article is relevant, the essence of the algorithm is precisely this property of bit division and it is right at the beginning of the article. I edited now to make sure there is no mis-understanding, the algorithm should work for any bit length.