# How can I store a series of bits in a variable using C language

Tags: c

How can I store this series of *bits* "000001111110001" (15bits) *in a variable* using *C* language.

I tried to store it into unsigned int:

```
unsigned int key=000001111110001;
```

but it doesn't, so please help me.

Comment: Convert it to hexadecimal or decimal and store it in a numeric type big enough (e.g. short, int...). Binary, decimal and hexadecimal are not a different types, it's just different ways to represent the same value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114140/writing-binary-number-system-in-c-code/15114188#15114188

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c

Answer (score 7):

Usually, the bits are broken down into 4 bits at a time, and then converted to hexadecimal representation:

```
unsigned int key = 0x03F1;
```

You can choose to break the bits down into 3 bits at a time and use octal representation (`01761`), or use regular decimal representation (`1009`).

If you want to use bits, you can build it up yourself like this:

```
unsigned int key = (1<<9)|(1<<8)|(1<<7)|(1<<6)|(1<<5)|(1<<4)|(1<<0);
```

Or, perhaps slightly more mnemonic:

```
#define b4(x) \
    ((((0##x >> 9) & 01) << 3) | \
     (((0##x >> 6) & 01) << 2) | \
     (((0##x >> 3) & 01) << 1) | \
     (((0##x >> 0) & 01) << 0))
#define b8(x1, x0) ((b4(x1) << 4) | b4(x0))
#define b16(x3, x2, x1, x0) ((b8(x3, x2) << 8) | b8(x1, x0))

unsigned int key = b16(0000,0011,1111,0001);
```

The macro `b4(x)` expects x to be 4 binary digits as input, and converts it into a 12 bit octal number (that is 3 bits is used to represent a single binary digit). Then, it converts that 12 bit octal number into a true 4 bit number. `b8(a,b)`, and `b16(a,b,c,d)` extend on `b4(x)`.

Fancier macro tricks may help you do it in an even more automated way. See for example [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__for.html).

Comment: What's unsigned bit? I guess you meant int (or maybe short).

Comment: @m0skit0 No, he did mean that unsigned.

Comment: @H2CO3 unsigned bit? There's no such type.

Answer (score 4):

If your compiler supports it (see FDinoff comment), you can represent an integer value in binary format if you precede it with a `0b`:

```
unsigned int x = 0b000001111110001;
```

Some alternatives:

- `000001111110001` is `1009` for ten-fingered humans, so just represent this value:

`unsigned int x = 1009;`

- `000001111110001` is `3F1` in hexadecimal, use `0x` prefix:

`unsigned int x = 0x3F1;`

- If you want things more complicated, represent it in octal form, use `0` prefix:

`unsigned int x = 01761;`

The thing is that no matter how you represent 1009 (000001111110001, 3F1, 1761), always the same bits will go in those `sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes (at least for the same endianness).

Comment: Note: this is a gcc Extension

Comment: @FDinoff thanks for pointing this out, I've included it in the answer.

Comment: An extension or C++11's user defined literals... hopefully, it will be back-ported to C some day...