# Bitwise operator & giving unexpected result

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators

The & operator deals with the binary format of a decimal number. So `10 & 9 = 8` because

```
1010 (10)
1001 (9)
=====
1000 (8)
```

This previous example runs fine. But when I try to do `010 & 010` I expect the result to be 10. However I get 8. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes 010 is decimal.

Comment: @Amir No, it's octal.

Comment: @AntonH Okay here's where I am confused ... why the first example was considered as decimal and the second as octal ... is it because of the 0 at the beginning ?

Comment: Please post some C source code

Comment: @Amir `10` is considered **decimal**, because it's default. When it starts with a `0`, it's considered **octal**. `0x` is considered as **hexadecimal**. As has been pointed out to me, there's no C standard for binary, although some compilers (such as GCC) consider `0b` as **binary** representation.

Comment: Good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114140/writing-binary-number-system-in-c-code

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Can you write an answer to mark solved.

Comment: @Amir Put an answer up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a number that starts with a `0` is considered as being octal, not binary.

`10` is considered **decimal**, because it's default. So the `10 & 9 = 8` test is resolved in decimal.

When it starts with a `0`, it's considered **octal**. So `010 & 010` is resolved in octal, as (in decimal): `8 & 8`.

`0x` is considered as **hexadecimal**.

And as `Oli Charlesworth` and `delnan` pointed out to me, there's no C standard for binary, although some compilers (such as GCC) consider `0b` as **binary** representation.

Interesting info here: [Writing binary number system in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114140/writing-binary-number-system-in-c-code)

Comment: Binary literals in C?

Comment: `0b010` is, unfortunately, only available in C++11. Or is there an equivalent extension in GNU C or something? Edit: Actually, there is such an extension: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612556/395760 -- whether it should be used is another question.