# How do I mute this error : "integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type"

Tags: c, binary

I have this school assignment in C where I will be corrected with the following flags :

```
-Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

So this harmless warning becomes an error and prevents compilation :

```
integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type
```

(code still works) but if I can't mute it my work will be considered wrong

Here is my code :

```
static unsigned long long   piece_to_map(unsigned short little)
{
    static unsigned short   row;
    unsigned long long      big;
    char                    i;
    unsigned long long      mask_left;
    unsigned long long      mask_top;

    mask_left = 9259542123273814144;
    mask_top = 18374686479671623680;
    row = 15;
    big = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i < 16)
    {
        big |= (little & (row << i)) << i;
        i += 4;
    }
    while ((big & mask_t) == 0)
        big = big << 8;
    while ((big & mask_l) == 0)
        big = big << 1;
    return (big);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to transform an unsigned short (representing a shape in a 4x4 square) to an unsigned long long representing the same shape in a 8x8 square having the shape cornered top-left. It works perfectly and according to my expectations, I just need to avoid having the warning. I was formerly using the (normally equivalent) binary expression instead and didn't get any warning

```
0b1111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and

```
0b1000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000
```

The problem is that the `0bxxxx` form is not standard C (As I read [in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114140/writing-binary-number-system-in-c-code)), therefore I am not allowed to use it.

I also tried

```
mask_left = (unsigned long long)9259542123273814144;
mask_top = (unsigned long long)18374686479671623680;
```

The compiler still tells me that the value is too large to be represened in a **signed** integer type. What am I doing wrong ? Is there any way to fix this at all ?

Comment: This is not a harmless warning.

Comment: `9259542123273814144` is a integer literal, `9259542123273814144L` is a long integer literal.

Comment: without the compiling flags, it is just a warning and the compilation succeeds. With the flags it's an error and the compilation fails. That's what I meant by "harmless"
@tkausl : thank you, I had never known about suffixes like that

Comment: It's in no way harmless: It's an overflow of a signed integer type, causing *undefined behavior*. That program could've started a new world war or killed some kittens!

Comment: @tkausl Both `9259542123273814144` and `9259542123273814144L`, as attempted un-suffixed decimal integer constants, exceed `LLONG_MAX` and do not fit.  Note: C does not specify _integer literal_.  It does specify _integer consonants_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Implicitly, the integer literal is `signed` and of course the values are too big for a `signed long long`, so you need to let the compiler know that they have type `unsigned`, like this

```
mask_left = 9259542123273814143U;
mask_top = 18374686479671623680U;
```

Comment: I had never heard about suffixes like that :D Thank you ! This is exactly what I was trying to achieve by casting the litteral in my second try

Comment: "the integer literal has type `int`".  No. `decimal literals can be `int`, long` or `long long`.  The issue is that both constants exceed  `LLONG_MAX` or `9223372036854775807`

Comment: Much better.  Detail: un-suffixed decimal integer _constants_ are signed.  OP could have done `mask_left = 0x8080808080808080; mask_top = 0xFF00000000000000;` which are hexadecimal integer _constants_ and would have quietly been unsigned as needed.   IMO, OP should be using hex _constants_ for masks anyways.

Comment: Thank you chux, I am new to binary operations, masks, shifting etc... I will note this advise for my next works

Answer (score 9):

Rewrite it with explicit size:

```
mask_left = 9259542123273814144uLL;
mask_top = 18374686479671623680uLL;
```

By writing it as `(unsigned long long) 9259542123273814144` it means to take the integer and then cast it longer.  Unfortunately, the integer is probably munged (by throwing away the higher bits to make it an `int`) and then increasing the size.

Comment: The "LL" is not needed.  The size explcit-ness is not the issue.  The problem is that `9259542123273814144 > LLONG_MAX`, so the compiler, beyond C specifications, finds the values fit as unsigned literals. (`unsigned long long`) as so warns.

Answer (score 3):

Signed integer literals cannot be larger than 2147483648.  For a number larger than that, you need to add the `LL` prefix, which tells the compiler it is a `long long`.  In your case, you want `ULL` as that designates an `unsigned long long`, which is what you're assigning to.

Comment: "Signed integer literals cannot be larger than 2147483648" is incorrect.  Signed integer literals cannot be larger than `LLONG_MAX` which is at least `9223372036854775807` or `pow(2,63)-1`