# Mask and extract bits in C

Tags: c, mask, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I've been looking at posts about masks, but I still can't get my head around how to extract certain bits from a number in C.

Say if we have an integer number,  `0001 1010 0100 1011`, its hexadecimal representation is `0x1A4B`, right? If I want to know the 5th to 7th number, which is `101` in this case, shall I use `int mask= 0x0000 1110 0000 0000, int extract = mask&number`?

Also, how can I check if it is `101`? I guess `==` won't work here...

Comment: if you wanna check the `5th` and `7th` number is `101` or not, then keep mask as `int mask= 0x0000 1010 0000 0000`. and then `ExNOR` it.. if `extract` `5th` and `7th` bit is `111`, then it is `101`

Comment: What is this `0x0000 1110 0000`? In case you want to show a bit series this is wrong, as `0x` indicates a hexa-decimal literal.

Comment: Some canonical questions are *[What is bit masking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/)* and *[How do I set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/)*.

Comment: And for setting bits: *[How do you set only certain bits of a byte in C without affecting the rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439078/how-do-you-set-only-certain-bits-of-a-byte-in-c-without-affecting-the-rest)* and *[How to replace bits in a bitfield without affecting other bits using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925755/how-to-replace-bits-in-a-bitfield-without-affecting-other-bits-using-c)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the [GCC extension `0b`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) to define binary literals:

```
int number = 0b0001101001001011; /* 0x1A4B */
int mask =   0b0000111000000000; /* 0x0E00 */
/* &'ed:     0b0000101000000000;    0x0A00 */
int extract = mask & number;     /* 0x0A00 */

if (extract == 0b0000101000000000)
/* Or if 0b is not available:
if (extract == 0x0a00 ) */
{
  /* Success */
}
else
{
  /* Failure */
}
```

Comment: Slightly related: *[Is there a way to do grouping in GCC binary literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774807/is-there-a-way-to-do-grouping-in-gcc-binary-literals)*

Answer (score 6):

Masking is done by setting all the bits except the one(s) you want to 0. So let's say you have a 8 bit variable and you want to check if the 5th bit from the is a 1. Let's say your variable is `00101100`. To mask all the other bits we set all the bits except the 5th one to 0 using the & operator:

```
00101100 & 00010000
```

Now what this does is for every bit except the 5th one, the bit from the byte on the right will be 0, so the result of the & operation will be 0. For the 5th bit, however, the value from the right bit is a 1, so the result will be whatever the value of hte 5th bit from the left byte is - in this case 0:

Now to check this value you have to compare it with something. To do this, simply compare the result with the byte on the right:

```
result = (00101100 & 00010000) == 00000000
```

To generalize this, you can retrieve any bit from the lefthand byte simply by left-shifting 00000001 until you get the bit you want. The following function achieves this:

```
int getBit(char byte, int bitNum)
{
    return (byte & (0x1 << (bitNum - 1)))
}
```

This works on vars of any size, whether it's 8, 16, 32 or 64 (or anything else for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

You need to mask **and** shift. Either shift the value you are comparing to, or the value you are comparing. I find it easier to think about by shifting the value you are comparing to. So if you're trying to extract the 5th to 7th digits (from the left), you shift **right** 9 positions (16-7) so that the 7th digit is now the rightmost, then apply 0x7 (111 in binary) as a mask to get only the rightmost three binary digits

```
int i = 0x1A4B;
if (((i >> 9) & 0x07) == 0x05) { // 0x05 = 101 in binary
    //do what you need to
}
```

Comment: you shifted out the relevant bits.

Comment: No I haven't, he's counting from the left, not the right!

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: How does this not answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

First, the digits in binary are (usually) counted from the right (10th and 12th digit) or you say 5th and 7th *most significant digits*.

```
int mask =  0x0E00;  // 0000 1110 0000 0000;
int extract = mask & number;
```

results in:

```
extract = 0000 1010 0000 0000
```

You can do

```
if (extract == 0x0A00 /*0000 1010 0000 0000*/){}
```

to test, or:

```
if (( extract >> 9 ) == 0x05){}
```

Both of the statements in the if will return true with your sample number.

Usually with a mask you will find yourself testing a single digit.  You could use a function like this to test it:

```
bool digit_value( unsigned int number, unsigned int digit)
{
    return (1 << digit) & number;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int number = 0x1A4B;
    int should_be_three = 0;
    should_be_three +=  digit_value(number, 10);
    should_be_three += !digit_value(number, 11);
    should_be_three +=  digit_value(number, 12);
    printf("%s", (should_be_three == 3?"it worked":"it didn't work"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your comarpison is wrong; not trying to compare against hex 0x101, but binary 101, which is 0x05

Comment: Thanks! but with `if (( extract >> 9 ) == 0x101)`, is `x101` actually `0001 0000 0001`? Should it be `if (( extract >> 9 ) == 0b101)`?

Comment: Yes, I did that a little wrong. Fixed now. (using pure hex)

Answer (score 0):

> shall I use `int mask= 0x0000 1110 0000 0000`, `int extract = mask&number`?-

Yes, you can do this.

> Also, how can I check if it is `101`?

Sure you can check this-
`0000 1010 0000 0000` which is `1280` in `int`.

```
extract== 1280
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to check bits one-by-one, not all at once.
At first, you create mask for interested bit:

```
int fifthBitMask = 1 << 4;
int fifthBitResult = number & fifthBitMask;

int seventhBitMask = 1 << 6;
int seventhBitResult = number & seventhBitMask;
```

Now, you can compare results with zero OR with mask.
Comparing with zero can be omitted, so you can just use simple if:

```
if (fifthBitResult && seventhBitResult)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Also, you can compare with masks. After operation &, in result will set only bits, which was set in mask.
So, it could like this:
    if (fifthBitResult == fifthBitMask && seventhBitResult == seventhBitMask)
    {
        // your code here
    }

So, if result of operation is equals to mask, you can do this with one operation:

```
int mask = 0x5 << 4; // 0x5 is hex representation of 101b
int result = number & mask;
if (result == mask)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your calculation for bits 7-6-5 is *incorrect*. You stated it was 101, but it is 010 (for x1a43).

Second of all, to get these bits (the value represented by these bits) you should do `&0xE0`.

`int my_bits_from_5to7 = number & 0xE0;`

Comment: Depends from which end you start counting.  Also depends if you are counting from 0 or 1.

Comment: @ilent2 nope, the bits order on most architectures is always the same: from right to left, and the first lowest bit is always number 0.

Comment: True, but if the OP is unfamiliar with bitwise operations it is likely that they would also be unaware of the conventions: such as counting from zero and right to left (while English is read from left to right).