# bitwise operations in c++, how to actually use it?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I understand

```
  11001110
& 10011000
= 10001000
```

but I want to test it myself

so I declare unsigned char and print it out, but it just gives me blank.

```
unsigned char result;
result= 11001110 & 10011000;

cout<<result;
```

Also tested with unsigned int, but it gives me 0, which is not what I expected

Comment: Those are decimal numbers.

Comment: You're currently defining decimal numbers.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2611764/311966) for how to specify a binary literal

Comment: that's because those numbers are decimal, not binary
read [this thread][1] about how to use binary in C++


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c

Comment: Well, we *will* be getting binary literals soon.

Comment: @Sergi0, actually [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537303/binary-literals/538101#538101) thread and answer, as C++11 is already here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`11001110` and `10011000` aren't binary numbers (at least in the compiler's mind).

Binary `11001110` is `206`, and `10011000` is `152`, so you actually want (I think):

```
result = 206 & 152;
```

or use a `std::bitset` and then print result as a binary.

Comment: Or wait until next year and (hopefully) write `0b11001110`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Too bad we won't be able to say `0b1011_1000_0001` AFAIK, though.

Comment: @chris `BOOST_BINARY(1011 1000 0001)`

Comment: @PiotrNycz, Interesting. Hopefully they figure out the digit separators problem, though.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using `hex` for testing

```
int a = 0xCE;    // 11001110
int b = 0x98;    // 10011000

int result = a & b;

cout << hex << result << endl;
```

or write a function to convert `result` to binary.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ you have to use hex to express bits number. Because 11001110 is 0XCE and 10011000 is 0X98

```
unsigned char b1 = 0XCE;
unsigned char b2 = 0X98;
unsigned char b = b1 & B2;
```

Comment: You don't have to use hex. Decimal and octal work fine as well. Hex is just nicer sometimes.

Comment: in standard c++, no octal data type you can use. if you use decimal(i know you mean integer here), it is hard to understand its bytes.

Comment: @Giswin C++ has octal literals, just like it has hexadecimal literals.

Answer (score 0):

11001110 in binary is NOT the same number in decimal.

Since c++ does not have a binary specifier (but has hex and octal), you need to use something like an online converter.

Get an online binary to decimal converter,
convert 11001110 to decimal, 10011000 to decimal, do the `&` operation,
Then convert the result from decimal back to binary.

Comment: Or you could just convert it in your head, or even the Windows calculator (if you use Windows). Or use `std::bitset`.

Comment: Fun exercise: write it yourself in `c++`. It's not hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `11001110`, you'll get a decimal, not a binary number, like Luchian pointed out.

To get a binary, you have to write `0b11001110`... The prefix `0b` means in gcc, clang and tcc, you are using binary system.

I don't know, what the Visual C++ Compiler will do with this prefix.