# How can I define custom literals?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, literals, user-defined-literals

I am converting some source code from one scripting language (PAWN) to a programming language (C++) on Windows.

The source code has millions of binary literals all over the place in the form of:

```
data[] = 
{
    0b11111111111011111110110111111110, 0b00000000001111111111111111111111,
    0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000,
    ///some million lines later...
    0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b11111111111111111111111110000000,
    0b11100001001111111111111111111111, 0b11110111111111111111111111111111,
    0b11111111111111111111111111111111, 0b11111111111111111111111111111111,
```

To my unfortunate luck Visual Studio 2013 doesn't support the user defined literals standard.

Is there any wya to achieve this somehow? 010101_b or something with C++, maybe with a little addition of boost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537303/binary-literals)

Comment: Search is your friend.

Comment: Why don't you write down a script using your favorite scripting language (mine's Python for example), that will take this file as input and generate a C++ fie as output?

Comment: not a bad idea indeed, some extra time but okay, hoever still doesn't answet the question and doing this over and over for millions of lines, I'd preffer a Replace-All-able solution ;) and I got one of the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537303/binary-literals , answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/537346/2548287 I just did: `#include <bitset>
const unsigned long GETBOOL(std::string str)
{
 return std::bitset<32>(str).to_ulong();
}
GETBOOL("11111111111011111110110111111110"),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise you to transform the source code with a script.

Anyway, if you're interested in Boost.PP:

```
#define FROM_BINARY(s, data, elem) sum(#elem+2)

constexpr auto sum(char const* str, std::uintmax_t val = 0) -> decltype(val)
{
    return !*str? val : sum(str+1, (val << 1) + *str - '0');
}

unsigned data[]
{
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REM_CTOR(BOOST_PP_SEQ_TO_TUPLE(
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(FROM_BINARY, , 
            BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(
    0b11111111111011111110110111111110, 0b00000000001111111111111111111111,
    0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000,
    ///some million lines later...
    0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b11111111111111111111111110000000,
    0b11100001001111111111111111111111, 0b11110111111111111111111111111111,
    0b11111111111111111111111111111111, 0b11111111111111111111111111111111))))
};
```

Note that this could horribly slow down compile time. So, again, try to transform the source dode once instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a simple, small, console program that converts the binary literals into hexadecimal literals.

Here's the process I would use:

1. Copy the file.
2. Using a text editor, remove everything before the first literal.
3. Remove everything after the last literal.
4. Save.
5. Replace the ", " with a newline.
6. Save.

You now have a text file with the binary literals, one per line.

Write a program to read in the file, convert to hexadecimal literals and output.

Then edit this file by pasting in all the missing stuff.