# Printing std::bitset in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, bitset, uint64

Consider the following code written in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {

    std::uint64_t a = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000;
    std::bitset<64> b(a);

    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is :

```
0000000000000000001001001001001001001001000000000000000000000000
```

Why this output does not correspond to the `a` value?

Comment: a is octal value....

Comment: Or rather, the literal being used to initialize it is octal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537303/binary-literals

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to write a binary number you need to use the `0b` prefix.

```
std::uint64_t a = 0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000;
std::bitset<64> b(a);
```

[Your example fixed and working live](http://ideone.com/6lzyki)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned your "binary" string is actually an octal representation of a much larger number. Alternative methods would be converting from a string, from the decimal representation or prefixing the string with '0b' to denote that a binary representation follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {

    std::bitset<64> foo (std::string("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000"));
    std::uint64_t  bar = foo.to_ulong();
    std::uint64_t beef = 0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000;
    std::bitset<64> dead (beef);

    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;
    std::cout << dead << std::endl;
    std::cout << beef << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```