Wrong result when XOR'ing two std::bitset
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::bitset<8> a = 10101010;
    std::bitset<8> b = 11111111;

    std::cout << (a ^ b);
}

When running the following code the result is:
11010101

Expected output is:
01010101

Am I doing something wrong?

I rolled back your edit because you should change a question to invalidate existing answer(s).

The issue is easily reproducible, and I don't think it is a typo, but rather lack of knowledge about types of literals. Voted to reopen.

Related to the binary literals part of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537303/binary-literals

10101010 is interpreted as a decimal integer as others noted. But note that 01010101 would be interpreted as an octal integer, and that surprises most C++ programmers who never use octal numbers. So beware.

@prapin that's a good point - added a side note about it to my answer below.

You initialize a and b with values which are decimal int literals (10101010, 11111111).
In order to use binary literals you need the 0b prefix:
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::bitset<8> a = 0b10101010;
    std::bitset<8> b = 0b11111111;

    std::cout << (a ^ b);
}

Output:
01010101

Live demo
More info about such literals: Integer literal.
A side note:
As mentioned above the current values you use are decimal integer literals.
But there is also the 0 prefix (without b) for octal literals.
So if you used e.g. 01010101 to initialize a or b, it would have been interpreted as an octal (base 8) value.
