# C++ Syntax - template <class ...Options>

Tags: c++, templates

Can't google this out so just looking for a quick answer. What this syntax means and is it standard C++?

```
template <class ...Options>
class list_base_hook;
```

The code is from boost libraries.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/intrusive/usage.html

Comment: The search keyword here is "variadic templates". It means you can pass many arguments. It is a C++11 feature, but Boost did some tricks to make that class work before C++03.

Comment: See [Variadic templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276188/variadic-templates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 it's a [variadic template parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).

Boost uses that syntax for "psuedo-variadic" templates from C++03 too - meaning it is a bunch typenames with defaults. Not exactly the same as C++11's variadics. Like this:

```
template <class opt1 = dummy, class op2 = dummy, class op3 = dummy, /* and so on up to a large N */>
class list_base_hook;
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a [variadic template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) which is part of the new C++11 standard.