# How can I get my va_list arguments to repeat itself?

Tags: c++

This is my first time working with `va_list` and stuff so I don't really know what I'm doing. Okay basically what I have is a bunch of numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) in the function ordered and I get them to print out. This works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

void ordered(int num1, double list ...);

void main()
{ 
    ordered(5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0);
}

void ordered(int num1, double list ...)
{
    va_list arguments;

    va_start(arguments, num1);

    list = va_arg(arguments, double);
    cout << "There are " << num1 << " numbers" << endl;

    do { 
        cout << list << endl; // prints out 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5
        list = va_arg(arguments, double);
    } while (list != 0);

    // at this point, list = 0

    va_end(arguments);
}
```

the problem is, after the `va_end(arguments);` or before it, I would like to get the program to print out my list a second time; basically print out 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 once more, without making another function. I tried to duplicate the code:

```
va_start(arguments, num1);

do { 
    cout << list << endl;
    list = va_arg(arguments, double);
} while (list != 0);

va_end(arguments);
```

without success. How can the program to repeat `list` once more, or is it not possible to do it again in the same function?

Comment: Good question actually, but i guess you also have to repeat the `va_start` and `va_end` part also.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work :( alright i just edited the code to show that

Comment: I don't think the signature of the function is right. `void ordered(int x, double y...)` means `void ordered(int x, double y, ...)`. That is, the varargs is not a sequence of `double`, but a sequence of unknown types that comes after a double argument. At the same time this means that your implementation is incorrect (drops the second argument to the function)

Comment: Have you considered variadic templates instead which is type-safe compared to `va_arg` etc... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276188/variadic-templates

Comment: this is actually a homework assignment, gotta follow specific instructions :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

void ordered(int num1, ...); // notice changed signature


int main(int,char**)
{ 
    ordered(5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0);
    return 0;
}

void ordered(int count, ...) // notice changed signature
{
    va_list arguments;

    va_start(arguments, count);

    cout << "There are " << count << " numbers" << endl;

    double value = 0.0;

    // notice how the loop changed
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) { 
        value = va_arg(arguments, double); 
        cout << value << endl; // prints out 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5
    } 

    // at this point, list = 0

    va_end(arguments);

    va_list arg2;
    va_start(arg2, count);

    cout << "There are " << count << " numbers" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) { 
        value = va_arg(arg2, double);
        cout << value << endl; // prints out 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5
    } 

    // at this point, list = 0

    va_end(arg2);

}
```

Comment: This does not tackle the question. He seems to be interested in printing the sequence *again* after the first pass.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Don't forget to scroll.

Comment: @RedX: Sorry, missed that part.

Answer (score 3):

From the man page:

> `va_end()`
>
> Each  invocation  of `va_start()`  must  be  matched by a corresponding invocation of `va_end()` in the same function.  After the
>   call `va_end(ap`) the variable ap is undefined.
>
> Multiple traversals of
>   the list, each bracketed by `va_start()` and `va_end()` are possible.

Could you show the code where you *tried that but it didn't work*?

NB. See also `va_copy`, with which you can make a duplicate of `arguments` before (destructively) traversing it, and then also traverse the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer (ignoring how varargs really works, I find it hard to find a valid use case outside of `printf`) is to copy the arguments yourself. Well, actually a simpler answer would be not to use varargs at all... Why are you not passing a container (or in C++11 using an `initializer_list`?)

Comment: And of course, even for `printf`, with C++11 variadic templates there's hardly any justification to using varargs...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I have not seen any implementation I like of `printf` without variadic args... Well, really I have not seen many implementations either. But currently the best candidate is a variadic args wrapper around `printf` that does the type checking and then forwards to the real `printf`, giving both the type safety of variadic templates and the performance of `printf` (in release mode the type tests can be `#ifdef`-ed out)

Comment: There is little benefit to that, given that compilers have specific checks for it. I think the main issue is that nobody really gave a thought to it; and personally if I went into recoding `printf`, I would probably take the opportunity to update the format string in order to cater to *objects* as well as plain data types (which is one of `printf` main flaws).