# What does this declare `void func(bool b ...)`?

Tags: c++, function

I answered this question [How can I get my va_list arguments to repeat itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659859/how-can-i-get-my-va-list-arguments-to-repeat-itself) and noticed the uncommon function declaration:

```
void ordered(int num1, double list ...);
```

First i thought the compiler would complain but clang 3.2 didn't and neither did g++ 4.7.2.

What does this declaration expand to? As what does it get interpreted?

Edit: I know about the ellipsis. But the normal form is `<return type> <function-name>(<argument1-type> <arg-name>, ...);` in the example the comma is missing.

Comment: This kind of reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625600/what-is-the-meaning-of-token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as:

```
void ordered(int num1, double list, ...);
```

Comment: And i guess that that declaration does not work with `va_arg`? My tests at least show they don't.

Comment: @RedX, It should work the same as any other C variadic function.

Answer (score 3):

This is a snippet of the grammar in the C++ standard:

```
parameter-declaration-clause:
  parameter-declaration-list[opt] ...[opt]
  parameter-declaration-list , ...
```

Basically the ellipsis can be preceded by `,` if the are other parameter declarations, but it need not be. The function declaration:

```
void f(int,double...);
```

really means:

```
void f(int,double,...);
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know the comma in this case was optional. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
void ordered(int num1, double list ...);
```

is same as:

```
void ordered(int num1, double list, ...);
```

Reference:
**Standard C++11 8.3.5.3/4:**

```
parameter-declaration-clause:
parameter-declaration-listopt ...opt
parameter-declaration-list , ...
```

> If the `parameter-declaration-clause` terminates with an ellipsis or a function parameter pack (14.5.3), the number of arguments shall be equal to or greater than the number of parameters that do not have a default argument and are not function parameter packs. Where syntactically correct and where `“...”` is not part of an `abstract-declarator`, ***`“, ...”` is synonymous with `“...”`.***

Answer (score 1):

The three dots (`...`) are called "ellipses" and denote a variable argument list. So you can pass as many arguments as you like (there is an OS-specified limitation, though). In this way, `printf` works, for example.

See [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html) for further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean the "..." right?

For some functions it is not possible to specify the number and type of all arguments expected in a call. Such a function is declared by terminating the list of argument declarations with the ellipsis (...).