# what do the (...) arguments in C++ do

Tags: c++

I'll get to the point, in thread.h the constructor to a thread is defined with what is below.

```
template<class _Fn,
    class... _Args>
    explicit thread(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
    {   // construct with _Fx(_Ax...)
    _Launch(&_Thr,
         _STD bind(_Decay_copy(_STD forward<_Fn>(_Fx)),
            _Decay_copy(_STD forward<_Args>(_Ax))...));
    }
```

I was wondering what the ... does
I've tried googling and looking on stackoverflow but the answer doesn't seem to anywhere!
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variadic templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276188/variadic-templates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) construct, called [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates) (follow the links)

Answer (score 2):

Its called [variadic template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template). It allows you to write templates with variable number of arguments. As far as I can tell here it allows you to define thread running function returning `_Fn` type with `_Args` arguments list by partial binding.

Comment: Basically allowing you to pass a number of arguments to a a function pointer.